# What is the normalized frequency distribution for the shortest tour length of identical circles in a larger circle?

Tags: probability

Suppose that I have a a circle of radius, $R$ with $n$-many non-overlapping circles in it where each circle has a radius, $r$.

The first block of code below generates random circles of the same radius inside a larger circle but not allowing overlapping. It has a set amount of tries to get a user input defined amount of small circles inside of it.

Then the second block of code finds the shortest tour (path) that connects centroids together. It touches every vertex exactly once except that it always returns back to the place that it started.

I am interested in the distribution of length of the shortest tours with this phenomenon.

Here is an example of circles inside of a circle:

[image: This is a photo of 20 small circles in a single big circle.]

Now, I am interested bounds for the parameter or name of the distribution formed by the Mathematica code:

```
generateCirclesSameRadius[numCircles_Integer, boundaryRadius_, circleRadius_, maxAttempts_Integer] :=
 Module[{circles = {}, attempt = 0, newCircle, canPlace},
  While[Length[circles] < numCircles && attempt < maxAttempts,
   newCircle = RandomPoint[Disk[{0, 0}, boundaryRadius - circleRadius]];
   canPlace = True;
   Do[
    If[Norm[newCircle - circle] < 2 circleRadius, canPlace = False; Break[];],
    {circle, circles[[All, 2]]}
    ];
   If[canPlace, AppendTo[circles, {circleRadius, newCircle}]];
   attempt++;
   ];
  circles
  ]
  
  
drawCircles[circles_] :=
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None], Circle[{0, 0}, boundaryRadius], 
   FaceForm[RandomColor[]], Circle[#[[2]], #[[1]]] & /@ circles}]
   
   fixedRadius = 0.1; (* Adjust based on the boundary radius and desired number of circles *)
boundaryRadius = 3;
numCircles = 20; (* Adjust based on available space and circle radius *)
maxAttempts = 200;
circles = generateCirclesSameRadius[numCircles, boundaryRadius, fixedRadius, maxAttempts];
drawCircles[circles]
```

Here are three examples of disks with Shortest Tours:

[image: This is one example with a shortest tour connecting the centroids.]

[image: This is a second example with a shortest tour connecting the centroids.]

[image: This is a third example with a shortest tour connecting the centroids.]

that was generated by the code:

```
ClearAll[graphShortestTourWithCircles];
graphShortestTourWithCircles[numCircles_Integer, boundaryRadius_, circleRadius_, maxAttempts_Integer] :=
 Module[{circles, centroids, totalDistance, order, hamiltonianCycleCentroids, dim = 2},
  
  (* Step 1: Generate non-overlapping circles *)
  circles = generateCirclesSameRadius[numCircles, boundaryRadius, circleRadius, maxAttempts];
  centroids = circles[[All, 2]]; (* Extract centroids of circles *)
  
  (* Step 2 & 3: Find the shortest tour among centroids *)
  {totalDistance, order} = FindShortestTour[centroids];
  hamiltonianCycleCentroids = centroids[[order]];
  
  (* Step 4: Visualize *)
  Graphics[
   {
    {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None], Circle[{0, 0}, boundaryRadius]}, (* Outer boundary circle *)
    FaceForm[RandomColor[]], Circle[#[[2]], #[[1]]] & /@ circles, (* Smaller circles *)
    {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[centroids]}, (* Centroids *)
    {Blue, Line[Append[hamiltonianCycleCentroids, hamiltonianCycleCentroids[[1]]]]} (* Shortest tour *)
   },
   Frame -> False
  ]
 ]
(* Function calls for generating circles and visualizing the shortest tour among them *)
fixedRadius = 0.1; (* Adjust based on the boundary radius and desired number of circles *)
boundaryRadius = 3;
numCircles = 50; (* Adjust based on available space and circle radius *)
maxAttempts = 200;
graphShortestTourWithCircles[numCircles, boundaryRadius, fixedRadius, maxAttempts]
```

If our distribution is given by fixed parameters for $P(R, r, n)$, and we took many trials, what is it the normalized distribution of Shortest Tour lengths? I don't know if it actually is normal or what else, and what the parameters would be (or at least very good estimates). I don't how many trials to take to get a good approximation either.

**As a note, I am not a Statistician and have taken only a very basic Statistics course. I am just curious.**

Comment: Although code is reproducible, it's a terrible way to describe something to people.  Please explain what it is intended to do and what this is a distribution of.

Comment: @whuber  I updated the OP and gave an explanation of what the code does and what the phenomenon is. Can you please tell me if it is okay for you? Sabbath starts soon, so if I don't reply for awhile that is why.